# Uncaught NSException while checking CharacterSet.isSuperset

Tags: ios, xcode, nscharacterset

I'm trying to verify if the input of an iOS text box is numeric only.

In this block, I'm getting an error in XCode 8.0 beta 2. What could I do?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let numbersOnly = CharacterSet.decimalDigits;
    let characterSetFromTextField = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string);
    let stringIsValid = numbersOnly.isSuperset(of: characterSetFromTextField);
```

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: You can check much easier with `let stringIsValid = Int(string) != nil`

Comment: @Larme I didn't get an error, but the app crashed with an uncaught NSException. When I tried to catch it, XCode stated that there is nothing to catch with a `try`.

Comment: @vadian I took a look at this and it seems to fail for numbers out of the Integer validity.

Comment: @Jublo Usually, when there is a message "Uncaught NSException", there are more details in console about the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in Swift 3.0

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2307

In the meantime you could iterate the characters in the string and use
`rangeOfCharacter(from: numbersOnly)` 
as a workaround or do something like 
`string.trimmingCharacters(in: numbersOnly).characters.count > 0`